# Casting anonymous function parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I've got a function inside of react (using typescript), where a container component is passing down variables to a child component. The variables are functions. However, when I'm passing these down, i get the "noImplicitAny" error. zoomIn and zoomOut are functions, and rest seems like an array. How should I assign a type to zoomIn, zoomOut, and ...rest?

```js
<TransformWrapper>
  {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, ...rest }) => (
    <TransformComponent>
      <Something onClick={zoomIn} />
     <TransformComponent/>
   )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of a function can be `Function` to match any function, but it's better to specify the parameter and return types like so:

`myFunc: (p1: type1, p2: type2) => returnType`

In the case of something like `zoomIn` it's probably `() => void`.

As for `rest`, you could set the type as `any[]`, though there may be a better type - it's unclear from the limited code sample provided. Remember though that the error is 'no *implicit* any', meaning you can make it an explicit any if you want.